# If $\phi : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $K,$ and $\phi(g) = h,$ find the fiber over $h$ in $G$, i.e. the set $\phi^{-1}(h).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $\phi : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $K,$ and $\phi(g) = h,$ find the fiber over $h$ in $G$, i.e. the set $\phi^{-1}(h).$

My thought is that:

Take $k \in K.$ Then $\phi(k) = e'$ where $e'$ is the identity in $ H$.

Then $\phi(gk) = \phi(g)\phi(k) = he' = h$.

So $\phi^{-1}(h) = gK $.

Looks pretty short, but would this proof enough?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Technically, you showed $gK \subseteq \phi^{-1}(h)$, you should also show the other inclusion.

Comment: What about $Kg$ ? You've just proved $gK\subset \phi^{-1}(h)$

Answer (score 3):

You have proven that $gK\subseteq \phi^{-1}(h)$ (and this proof is fine). It remains to show inclusion the other way.

Let $g'\in\phi^{-1}(h)$, which is to say $\phi(g')=h$. Then we have $\phi(g^{-1}g')=e'$, so $g^{-1}g'\in K$, which means $g'=gg^{-1}g'\in gK$.

Comment: What about $Kg$ ?

Comment: @marwalix What about it? It happens to be equal to $gK$, but it's completely superfluous. We are asked to describe $\phi^{-1}(h)$, and $gK$ does that just fine.

Comment: @marwalix $K$ is normal so $gK=Kg$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster and so the proof is complete.

Comment: Sure.  @marwalix  But Arthur proved the fibre is equal to $gK$ without needing this fact.

Comment: How does using $Kg$ help the proof?